# mysql real escape on array that contains objects?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysql-real-escape-string

I have an array that I need to sanitize before putting it in a cell on a mysql database. The code i'm trying seems to work. But as soon as there are characters like ' it throws errors and thats not good. Here's what i've tried, any ideas whats wrong?

```
 function submitLogDb($array,$id,$title)
       {
            function mysql_real_escape_array($var) 
            {
                foreach($var as $line)
                {
                mysql_real_escape_string($line['msg']);
                }

              return $var;
            }


            $title=mysql_real_escape_string($title);

            $array=mysql_real_escape_array($array);

            return mysql_query("INSERT INTO logs (text,id,title) VALUES ('".serialize($array)."','$id','$title')");


       }
```

EDIT:
Just incase it helps, heres what some of the objects might look like in the array:

```
[1] 
  icon = ""
  msg = "this is a test"
  name = "Them: "
  systemMsg = 0
[2]
  icon = ""
  msg = "yep it sure is"
  name = "You: "
  systemMsg = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` the output of serialization of the array.

```
$data_to_insert = mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($array));
```

Comment: perfect! I didn't consider it because I didn't think the serialized version would be readable like that. Thanks!